# .htaccess making a fake subfolder after main domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I want/need to rewrite all my product urls

for example a product url in three languages.

```
mainurl.com/en/outdoor/wood-table
mainurl.com/de/außenbereich/holz-tisch 
mainurl.com/it/esterno/tavolo-legno
```

What url i want/need is:

```
mainurl.com/products/en/outdoor/wood-table
mainurl.com/products/de/außenbereich/holz-tisch 
mainurl.com/products/it/esterno/tavolo-legno
```

Running the Shop Local with xampp in the Root-Folder *htdocs*.

**How can i rewrite this url via .htaccess and making this fake subfolder after the mainurl?**

This is the original .htaccess file that is included in the Shopsystem *xt:commerce*:

```
# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xtAdmin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*) $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: sorry but this is not working. maybe i should mention that i run the shop local with xampp in the rootfolder htdocs.

When i put your code after RewriteEngine on nothing happens at all. The URLs are still the same and an URL with /product/ still dont exist.

Comment: You mean `http://mainurl.com/products/en/outdoor/wood-table` is giving you 404? Can you show your current full .htaccess?

Comment: Yes it gives me a 404!
This is my full .htacces including your codesnippet:
[link](http://pastebin.com/ekdSU2DJ)

Comment: What is URL shown in browser when you get 404 and what is exact error displayed in browser?

Comment: this is the current link that is working:
http://localhost/en/outdoor/wood-table

When i put your code snippet nothing happens at all.
When i write /products/ or /product/ just infront of /en/ then i get a 404.
Page not found

    Sorry, your requested page was not found

Comment: To test the rule add `R` flag to make it `RewriteRule ^product/(.*) $1 [L,NC,R]` and then retest

Comment: I did put the R now but the urls still dont change at all.
When i manually put /product/ now in front of /en/ i get a 403 error and my url adress changes automatic to http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/en/outdoor/wood-table

Comment: ok make that rule as: `RewriteRule ^product/(.*) /$1 [L,NC,R]` and retest

Comment: Ok this looks better now. the urls still didnt change but when i put /product/ infront of /en/ it automatically deletes the /product/ and jumps back to the product.
example:
`working link: localhost/en/outdoor/wood-table`
`this link: localhost/product/en/outdoor/wood-table jumps back to localhost/en/outdoor/wood-table`
now i need the reverse result

Comment: So you can see my rule is working fine. `404` is probably coming from your `index.php`. Are you using some framework? What do you mean by reverse result?

Comment: im not using any framework, im using the shopsystem xt:commerce.
with the reverse result i mean that /product/ needs to be added in the url in front of /en/ not deleted. 
current link i dont need: `localhost/en/outdoor/wood-table = NOT GOOD` link i need: `localhost/product/en/outdoor/wood-table = GOOD` i hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: To make it work first `RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC]` rule must work when you enter URL as: `localhost/product/en/outdoor/wood-table` in browser. If you get 404 then your `shopsystem xt:commerce` is conflicting with internal rewrites and we can't do much.

Comment: maybe thats the problem... its still not working but thanks for your help!